# Regex pattern where matches img tags

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, regex, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC, look at this example where we have the following HTML code:

```
<p>Duma</p><img url='..' /><p>Duma</p>
```

I would like that print only the content of the tags, as:

```
Duma [IMAGE] Duma
```

Removing the image (showing [IMAGE]) tags and showing only the text (as innerText)

I decided to create an extension where until this moment, shows only

```
Duma Duma

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string StripHtml (this string inputString)
    {
       return Regex.Replace 
         (inputString, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

How can I do to add [IMAGE] everytime the regex matches with `img tags`

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string StripHtml (this string inputString)
    {
       return Regex.Replace(
       Regex.Replace(inputString, "<img.*?>", "[IMAGE]"), "<.*?>", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

It actually calls two Reges.Replace() one inside other. !st one replaces the `<img ...>` tag to [IMAGE] followed by replacing rest of string leaving only the content inside `<p>` tag.